# Not able to continue if-statement when checking if file already exists

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I am trying to code a programme where user can create a profile, modify it, review it and so on. After all this information is gathered, the data should be saved in a file.

My code was alright until I added this last bit. I am not able to create a condition where my programme checks if the file has already been created or not. If the file already exists, a message should be thrown to user saying so. If the file was not created, the programme should carry on asking user all the questions to create the profile.

I am a bit stuck. With this code, the part of "What's your name" is duplicated. The programme is asking twice the user his/her name and I am not able to figure out how to fix it. This is what I have done so far:

import os

```
def ask_option():
    # Print menu and return chosen option
    print("\nMENU\n")
    print("******************")
    print("Create new profile, click 1.")
    print("Modify profile, click 2.")
    print("Review profile, click 3.")
    print("Updating currently binge watchting TV show, click 4.")
    print("Leave the programme, click 5.")

    option = int(input("\nWhat do you what to do?\n"))
    print("\n******************\n")
    return option 

def ask_data():
    # Ask and return all the data provided by user
    name = input("What's your name? ").capitalize()
    surname = input("What's your surname?: ").capitalize()
    year = int(input("Which year were you born? "))
    age = 2022 - year
    
    return name, surname, year, age

def print_data(name, surname, year, age):
    # Print all the data provided by user
    profile = name, surname, year, age
    print()
    print("Name:", name, surname)
    print("Age:", age, "years old")
    return profile  

def save_data(name, surname, year, age):
    # Guarda los datos del usuario en un archivo
    file = open(name + ".user", "w", encoding = "UTF-8")
    file.write(name + "\n" + surname + "\n" + age + "\n")
    file.close()

def create_profile():
# Check if file with user data already exists. If that is so, return message. If there is no file, carry on asking user data to create profile
    carryon = True
    while carryon:
    name = input("What's your name? ").capitalize()
    if not os.path.isfile(name + ".user"): 
          name, surname, year, age = ask_data()
          save_data(name, surname, year, age)
          print("\nYour profile has been created.\n")
          print_data(name, surname, year, age)
          carryon = False
    else:
          print("Your profile already exists.")
```

Comment: `continue` is a protected keyword, are you sure you can set a value to it? I think you should test on `os.path.exists` and `continue`. Better logic than testing on the negative.

Comment: The code you included has indentation errors. In general, you should not redefine builtins and standard functions, but you *cannot* redefine keywords.

Comment: `continue` is a keyword.  You cannot assign a value to it.  This code cannot possibly run.  Please post your real code.

Comment: Sorry! I translated the code from my Spanish version and didn't notice the keyword Continue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop here, right?  Either it exists, and you return, or it doesn't exist, and you create it.

```
def create_profile():
    # Check if file with user data already exists. If that is so, return message. If there is no file, carry on asking user data to create profile
    name = input("What's your name? ").capitalize()
    if os.path.isfile(name + ".user"):
        print("Your profile already exists.")
        return
 
    name, surname, year, age = ask_data()
    save_data(name, surname, year, age)
    print("\nYour profile has been created.\n")
    print_data(name, surname, year, age)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I like the code you provide but I am noticed that it throws the same error than my if statement. If there is no file already created, the user is asked twice "What's your name?": one to chekc if the file exists and the other one to create it. But I do not know how to fix the code in order to only aks once.

Comment: You didn't mention that as a problem.  You haven't included all the code here, so we can't advise you on the structure.  You should ask for the name once, and then pass that to the functions that need it.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with the code
`continue` is a keyword and should be reserved. Also there is no need for a `while` as `continue` will handle this well.

```
    def create_profile():
            name = input("What's your name? ").capitalize()
            if os.path.isfile(name + ".user"):
                print("Your profile already exists")
                continue
            name, surname, year, age = ask_data()
            save_data(name, surname, year, age)
            print("\nYour profile has been created.\n")
            print_data(name, surname, year, age)
```

Comment: NOTE: This code may have indentation issues as I am on mobile

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried but it always throwns me an indentention error (which, to be honest, I do not really understand because I think it is ok), but I have tried just in case different indentention and nothing changed.